# How does this Angular "button" actually work?

Tags: html, angular

This clickable element:  [image]

when inspected in chrome is represented by this html:

```
    <div _ngcontent-kkl-c57="" class="cursor-pointer text-tibco-gray-L14 hover:text-tibco-gray-L16 ng-star-inserted">
        <a _ngcontent-kkl-c57="" class="flex items-center">
            <tss-icon _ngcontent-kkl-c57="" class="flex mr-2 w-4 h-4">
                <div class="fill-current w-full">
                    <svg
                        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <polygon points="11 7 11 4 15 8 11 12 11 9 4 9 4 7 11 7"></polygon>
                        <path d="M8,2V1H1.75A.75.75,0,0,0,1,1.75v12.5a.749.749,0,0,0,.75.75H8V14H2V2Z"></path>
                    </svg>
                </div>
            </tss-icon>
            <span _ngcontent-kkl-c57="" title="Log out">Log out</span>
        </a>
    </div>
```

It works (results in some actions in response to a click).
**My question is how does this html result in a click event being captured and handled?**

To clarify, if I saw

```
<div onclick="handler()"/>
```

or

```
<a href = "...
```

I would understand.
In this case I don't even see any of the elements with an attribute that looks like onclick might be captured or at least the element can be uniquely identified in case onclick is captured in some ancestor of it. I am obviously very new to Angular and it's probably something basic that I am missing.

Comment: The element has an [event listener added](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) via Javascript. Event listeners added through code aren't properties that would show up in the inspector. Nothing to do with Angular specifically.

Comment: Ok, but how would that code add the event listener to an element that does not have an id or name or any unique identifier?

Comment: The element is *also* created by code so it doesn't need to be searched for in the DOM.

Comment: Aha! Just tested that notion - it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The question was really answered by Guy Incognito in a comment, but to make it clear what the answer is, and to prove to myself that it actually works I made a test page. The HTML file contains:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function onInit()
            {
                const element = document.createElement("button"); 
                element.innerText = "Click Me";
                element.addEventListener("click",onInit);
                document.body.appendChild(element);
                alert("HELLO");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="onInit()">
    </body>
</html>
```

When loaded in Chrome and "Inspect"ed it shows this:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script>
                function onInit()
                {
                    const element = document.createElement("button"); 
                    element.innerText = "Click Me";
                    element.addEventListener("click",onInit);
                    document.body.appendChild(element);
                    alert("HELLO");
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="onInit()">
            <button>Click Me</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Has new button that works. It's obvious now, but somehow it was not obvious to me before so I think it should be exposed to others with the same question.